# Проблема с настройкой LoadBalancer в Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Всем доброго дня!
Запущен тестовый кластер Kubernetes (RKE - Rancher Kubernetes) в локальной сети.

Приложение запущено и работает

```
# cat ibank-deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ibank-api-deployment
  namespace: ibank-at
  labels:
    app: ibank-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: ibank-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: ibank-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ibank-api
          image: myimage:latest
          env:
          - name: JAVA_OPTS
            value: '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ...'
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: '1300m'
            limits:
              cpu: '2000m'
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /public/json?service=info
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /public/json?service=info
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 10
```

Далее, мне нужно вывести это приложение наружу. С NodePort всё хорошо работает. Но это не то, что мне нужно. Мне нужен статический порт. Делаю настройку для LoadBalancer

```
# cat ibank-loadbalancer.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ibank-api
  namespace: ibank-at
spec:
  selector:
    name: ibank-api
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8083
    targetPort: 8080
  loadBalancerIP: 10.10.169.24
  type: LoadBalancer
```

И вижу следующее

```
# rancher kubectl get service -n ibank-at
NAME        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
ibank-api   LoadBalancer   10.43.21.56   <pending>     8083:32352/TCP   20m
```

Аналогичный статус "Pending" вижу и в вебморде ранчера и для сервиса и для балансера.
Если я правильно понял ту документацию, которую накопал, то вопрос в том, что кубер ожидает "белый" адрес. Но у меня кластер тестовый и запущен в локальной сети. Я не могу дать ему белый адрес.
Подскажите, как обойти проблему или дайте волшебного пендаля что и где искать, чтобы балансер заработал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

Заменить

```
loadBalancerIP: 10.10.169.24
```

на

```
externalIPs:
 - 10.10.169.24
```